# What is the semantics of Long.toInt in Scala?

Tags: scala

If long.isValidInt, then obviously, it evaluates to the corresponding Int value.

But what if it's not? Is it equivalent to simply dropping the leading bits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it equivalent to simply dropping the leading bits?

Yes. To verify this you can either just try it or refer to the [following section of the Scala specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#numeric-value-types):

> Conversion methods toByte, toShort, toChar, toInt, toLong, toFloat, toDouble which convert the receiver object to the target type, using the rules of Java's numeric type cast operation. The conversion might truncate the numeric value (as when going from Long to Int or from Int to Byte) or it might lose precision (as when going from Double to Float or when converting between Long and Float).

And the [corresponding section of the Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

Why this isn't just described in the ScalaDocs for the `toInt` method, I don't know.